# Limitations of Dynamic Approval process

Tags: approval-process, dynamic

What is Dynamic Approval Process(with an example)? 
What are the advantages and limitations of dynamic approval process.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE nirmala, this is very open ended at present and has been flagged by a user to be closed because of that. Questions here should really be about a specific problem. Can you add some context around it to make of the form "We want to do X will dynamic approval processes work for this?", that way we can leave it open and hopefully you'll get more useful information that pertains to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the asnwerfrom [Creating a multi-approver approval process](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/creating-a-multi-approver-approval-process)

> This is all definitely possible inside Salesforce's approval process.
>   It utilizes [approval steps](https://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm). This would utilize a 3 step approach.
>
> Here is a [Youtube demonstration of a scenario of requiring two
>   approvers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fM3xHN8M9-8). Here is another Youtube video from a [Dreamforce session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8XmfBQDSpY)
>   that goes more into depth on workflow and approval process.
>
> Finally, here are some more [examples of approval process to help you
>   along](http://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_useful_approval_processes.htm).